# Programmatically generate image source url

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-mobile

How can I generate the image source via a JavaScript function?

I am using JQuery mobile to create a list with a thumbnail:

```
$("#nav").append(

            '<li>' + '<a>' + '<img src=""/>' +
                '<h3>' + surName + ', ' + firstName + ' (' + any + 
                ')' + '</h3>' + '<p>' + another + '</p>' +
                '</a>' + '</li>'
        );
        })
        $("#nav").listview("refresh");
```

The image source is changing each time I iterate through my list-creation, this means, the url for the image is created on the fly via:

```
function getPicUrl(empID) {

    var url = "url/loadEmployees/"
    url = url + empID;
    url = url + "/images/thumb";

    return url;

}
```

Which means the image source must be somehow added ... I don't know how to do this.

Something like `<img src="getPicUrl(variable)">` ... is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add your function to be called where the src is:

```
$("#nav").append(

        '<li>' + '<a>' + '<img src="' + getPicUrl(idVariable) + '"/>' +
            '<h3>' + surName + ', ' + firstName + ' (' + any + 
            ')' + '</h3>' + '<p>' + another + '</p>' +
            '</a>' + '</li>'
    );
    })
    $("#nav").listview("refresh");
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to catch somehow an 404 error (which would mean the url doesnt provide the image)...?

Comment: should be possible: http://jsbin.com/ixedur/edit Im not to sure when you are running things, but i moved the code a bit just to use events with jquery (error event), if it gets an error, remove the img element.

Comment: not sure if I get the point how to catch the 404, the $('img') refers to every image object right? would it be possible to give a ID to the img object, then do some kind of 'try to load the picture' if it is not loading and returning an 404, then please chose the local picture ab.png .. is this possible? thank you!

Comment: well if you write $("img") its all the image current in the DOM, but I have $("img", newItem) meaning all the images in the newItem so thats not a problem. and just change the error event if its an error then change the src to 'ab.png' instead of deleting it like: http://jsbin.com/ixedur/2/edit

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do `$('img').attr('src',getPicUrl(empID));`